# mcollective can't find puppet ddl, though it exists

Tags: puppet, centos7, mcollective

```
[vagrant@puppetserver ~]$ ls /usr/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/agent/
filemgr.ddl  nettest.ddl  package.ddl  puppet.ddl  service.ddl
filemgr.rb   nettest.rb   package.rb   puppet.rb   service.rb

[vagrant@puppetserver ~]$ mco rpc puppet runonce -v

The rpc application failed to run: Can't find DDL for agent plugin 'puppet'

Can't find DDL for agent plugin 'puppet' (RuntimeError)
        from /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mcollective/ddl/base.rb:83:in `loadddlfile'  <----
```

All the required packages are installed, I guess.

```
Package mcollective-puppet-agent-1.11.1-1.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package mcollective-puppet-client-1.11.1-1.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package mcollective-puppet-common-1.11.1-1.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Plus **facts** seems to be working improperly.

```
[vagrant@puppetserver ~]$ mco facts hostname
No values found for fact hostname

Finished processing 2 / 2 hosts in 42.06 ms
```

But I can **ping** all these nodes.

```
[vagrant@puppetserver ~]$ mco ping
puppetserver.example.com                 time=10.54 ms
client.example.com                       time=49.43 ms
```

Puppet plugin is not visible in node's inventory.

```
Agents:
      discovery       rpcutil

   Data Plugins:
      agent           collective      fact
      fstat
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Not sure if you ever figured this out. In my case, checking the mcollective log after startup indicated a syntax error. What do your logs say?